# How to ignore errors but not skip rows in redshift copy command

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a nested json as my source file in S3 and I am trying to copy this file into redshift. 
My issues with this are as follows,

1. I use MAXERROR - I need to skip certain errors because the source file is missing certain fields in some cases and has them in other
2. I use a JSONPATH file - to pick the fields that I need to copy to redshift
3. All the columns in the table are varchar

Obviously, since I am using maxerror the copy command executes successfully but the table has 0 records. Here is my copy command

```
COPY public.table(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6)
from 's3://bucket/filename'
credentials 'redshift'
format as JSON 'jsonpathfile.json'
timeformat 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS'
EMPTYASNULL ACCEPTANYDATE ACCEPTINVCHARS TRUNCATECOLUMNS maxerror 100 ;
```

If I check into stl_load_errors it keeps saying

> Invalid JSONPath format: Member is not an object.

Does this mean the copy command is not able to find even one object that fits the jsonpath file?
Which is definitely not true. I inferred the schema of the input file to design the jsonpath file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from [COPY Examples - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#copy-from-json-examples-using-jsonpaths):

```
copy category
from 's3://mybucket/category_object_paths.json'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole' 
json 's3://mybucket/category_jsonpath.json';
```

The path to the `jsonpath` file is specified fully, whereas your example just refers to the filename.

Try specifying the full path starting with `s3://` and see whether that helps.

Comment: Yes of course, for simplicity I mentioned just the filename but I did include the full s3:// path.